# How to illustrate rain type by using a timer in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-c#-express-2010

I am currently doing a small project on rain monitoring system. for this project, I want to show if it a heavy rain, medium rain, light rain or no rain by using a timer in Visual C# 2008. this project consist of 6 level water sensor that detect water at every level. by using a timer :

If the water reach level 6 in less than 30 seconds, it is Heavy Rain.
If the water reach level 6 more than 60 seconds, it is Light Rain.
If the water reach level 6 in less than 60 seconds, it is Medium Rain.
If no water detected at level 1, it is No Rain.

For now, I have done some program to detect the water at every level.
This is what my code look like.

```
if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "1")
    {
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Level0;
        label8.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        Label1.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label2.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label7.Text = "Rain Detected";

        sql = "INSERT INTO RMSDatabase(Level_0)values('" + DateTime.Now + "')";
        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "RMSDatabase");

    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "2")
    {
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Level1;
        Label1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        Label2.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label7.Text = "1 Litre";

        sql = "INSERT INTO RMSDatabase(Level_1)values('" + DateTime.Now + "')";
        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "RMSDatabase");

    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "3")
    {
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Level2;
        Label2.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label7.Text = "2 Litre";

        sql = "INSERT INTO RMSDatabase(Level_2)values('" + DateTime.Now + "')";
        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "RMSDatabase");

    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "4")
    {
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Level3;
        Label3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label7.Text = "3 Litre";

        sql = "INSERT INTO RMSDatabase(Level_3)values('" + DateTime.Now + "')";
        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "RMSDatabase");

    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "5")
    {
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Level4;
        Label4.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White;
        Label7.Text = "4 Litre";

        sql = "INSERT INTO RMSDatabase(Level_4)values('" + DateTime.Now + "')";
        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "RMSDatabase");

    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "6")
    {
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Level5;
        Label5.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Label7.Text = "5 Litre";
        if (Label7.Text == "5 Litre")
        {
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(Properties.Resources.alarm, Microsoft.VisualBasic.AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop);
            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort.Close();
            }
            try
            {
                serialPort.PortName = Form2.DefaultInstance.ComboBox1.Text;
                serialPort.BaudRate = 96000;
                serialPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;

                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.Write("ATDT" + Form2.DefaultInstance.ComboBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Alarm system initiated!", "Warning!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            My.Computer.Audio.Stop();
            serialPort.Close();

            sql = "INSERT INTO RMSDatabase(Level_5, Contact_Number)values('" + DateTime.Now + "', '" + Form2.DefaultInstance.ComboBox2.Text + "')";
            da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds, "RMSDatabase");

        }
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == null)
    {
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Level0;
    }
```

The Heavy Rain, Medium Rain, Light Rain and No Rain will display by using label.
Can someone help me how to put the timer based on the condition I have give above?

This is edited version that working.

```
Dim timercount As integer = 0
If e.KeyChar.ToString = "1" Then
        Timer2.Interval = 1000 '1000 milisecond is equal to 1 second
        Timer2.Enabled = True 'Start the timer
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level0
        Label8.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Label1.BackColor = Color.White
        Label2.BackColor = Color.White
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White
        Label9.Text = "Rain Detected"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_0)values('" & DateTime.Now & "')"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

    ElseIf e.KeyChar.ToString = "2" Then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level1
        Label1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label2.BackColor = Color.White
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White
        Label7.Text = "1 Litre"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_1)values('" & DateTime.Now & "')"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

    ElseIf e.KeyChar.ToString = "3" Then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level2
        Label2.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White
        Label7.Text = "2 Litre"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_2)values('" & DateTime.Now & "')"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

    ElseIf e.KeyChar.ToString = "4" Then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level3
        Label3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White
        Label7.Text = "3 Litre"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_3)values('" & DateTime.Now & "')"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

    ElseIf e.KeyChar.ToString = "5" Then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level4
        Label4.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White
        Label7.Text = "4 Litre"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_4)values('" & Date.Now & "')"
        da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

    ElseIf (e.KeyChar.ToString() = "6" And timercount > 60) Then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level5
        Label5.BackColor = Color.Red
        Label7.Text = "5 Litre"
        Label9.Text = "Light Rain"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_5)values('" & Date.Now & "')"
        da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

    ElseIf (e.KeyChar.ToString() = "6" AndAlso timercount > 30 And timercount <= 60) Then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level5
        Label5.BackColor = Color.Red
        Label7.Text = "5 Litre"
        Label9.Text = "Medium Rain"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_5)values('" & Date.Now & "')"
        da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

    ElseIf (e.KeyChar.ToString = "6" And timercount <= 30) Then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level5
        Label5.BackColor = Color.Red
        Label7.Text = "5 Litre"
        Label9.Text = "Heavy Rain"

        If Label9.Text = "Heavy Rain" Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.alarm, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
            If serialPort.IsOpen Then
                serialPort.Close()
            End If
            Try
                With serialPort
                    .PortName = Form2.ComboBox1.Text
                    .BaudRate = 96000
                    .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                    .DataBits = 8
                    .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                End With

                serialPort.Open()
                serialPort.Write("ATDT" & Form2.ComboBox2.Text & vbCrLf)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)

            End Try

            MsgBox("Alarm system initiated!", MessageBoxIcon.Warning, "Warning!!")

            My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
            serialPort.Close()

            sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_5, Contact_Number)values('" & DateTime.Now & "', '" & Form2.ComboBox2.Text & "')"
            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
            da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is what I try using IF statement inside If ElseIf statement..but it's not working.

```
Dim timercount As integer = 0
Dim timercount2 As integer = 10
If e.KeyChar.ToString = "1" Then
        Timer2.Interval = 1000 '1000 milisecond is equal to 1 second
        Timer2.Enabled = True 'Start the timer
        Timer3.Interval = 1000
        Timer3.Enabled = True
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Level0
        Label8.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Label1.BackColor = Color.White
        Label2.BackColor = Color.White
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White
        Label9.Text = "Rain Detected"

        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Level_0)values('" & DateTime.Now & "')"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")

        If timercount2 = 0 Then
            Timer2.Enabled = False
            Timer3.Enabled = False
            Label8.BackColor = Color.White
            Label9.Text = "Just a waterdrop"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse me, but did you really called your ddbb Rain Monitoring System Database, with spaces and all??

Comment: Don't create queries using string concatenation, you leave yourself vulnerable to SQL Injection.  You should instead be using parameterized queries.

Comment: @Oscar owh...forgot about that. this is edited table. and before this I am using Table1 and it run perfectly. thanks for telling me about that.

Comment: @Servy sorry sir. I seems to hardly understand what you are saying at above.

Comment: @user2308475 You're creating your SQL queries as strings by adding different strings together.  When those strings are based on user input, which is the case for some of your queries, the user can all sorts of really bad things, such as `"'; drop table Rain Monitoring System Database; --"`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by your code it seems you're using windows forms. Add an instance of System.Windows.Form.Timer, initialize it and add an event handler for the thick event. Inside the event handler code, do whatever you want to do.

See this thread:
[Winforms Timer for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174733/winforms-timer-for-dummies)

However, I highly recommend to create a Weather class, and use events to signal rain conditions. I'm talking about using an object oriented approach, which your code lacks.

Comment: sir, thank you for giving me some idea. I seems to know what I have to do. Thank you very much. I will try to work it out. I'll ask here again if I face some problem.

Comment: sir, can you help me with the code sir? I can't make it work. It kind of confusing for me.

Comment: Show me what  you got till now. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: sorry for late reply..just this morning i manage to do the code..and it might be kind of messy, but it still do what i want it to do..hehe..by the way, is it possible to do this kind of If statement inside of IF ElseIf statement..?

If....Then
  (what it have to do)
  If....Then
  (what it have to do)
  End If
End If

it kind of like, 
If...Then > If....Then > End If > ElseIf...Then > ElseIf....Then > End If

Comment: It's possible, but ugly and hard to maintain. As I said, you should use an Object Oriented approach in your code, what's not the case.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Object Oriented. I try to learn about using the Case statement, but still can't understand it very well..I'll post what i try to do now..

Comment: in the edited above, I using VB and not VC#. Because I much more understand when using VB.