# How to define a timers interval from a textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and I am coding a simple auto typer, and I am trying to make it so users' can set their own interval. I tried using:

```
timer1.Interval = textbox1.Text;
```

but that doesn't seem to be working. I put that code in a button.. How do I get this to work? And why isn't it working?

Comment: Text is a string value and Interval requires an int value. You need to convert the string to an int.

Comment: Since you're expecting only numbers, why not use a NumericUpDown control instead of a textBox?

Comment: You question is vague. The main error is the assignment of a string (Text property) to an integer property (int Interval) and in C# this is not allowed. But saying _doesn't work_ is not very helpful here. Did you set the event handler for the Timer.Tick event. Did you check that the value is not to low for the timer resolution? [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174733/winforms-timer-for-dummies)

Comment: If there's an answer you that addresses your question, it's considered polite to mark it as accepted:)

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this:

```
int value;

// if it is really a value
if (int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out value))
{
    // if the value is not negativ (or you can enter the lower boundary here)
    if (value > 0)
    {
        timer1.Interval = value;
    }
}
```

As Steve mentioned in his comment, you need to connect a callback function to the `timer1.Elapsed` event (Attention: The name of the event differs depending on the timer you are using. It could also be timer1.Tick). You would do this by using the following code:

```
timer1.Elapsed += TimerElapsedCB;
```

and you need to define the callback function itself:

```
private void TimerElapsedCB(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something here ;-)
    // (e.g. access the signal time by using e.SignalTime)
}
```

Comment: Given the constraints I think that this is the best solution, but I would ask to the original poster if he has setup an event handler for the timer ticks _doesn't work_ is really vague. (and notice that the value of Interval is milliseconds so, a lower boundary is probably mandatory here.)

Comment: Ouch, now we have the problem to understand what kind of timer he is using. Well the questions on timers are always a mess, I leave the solution to you.... :-)

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.Interval = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
```

but keep in mind that user must enter a number , so you might need to handle the case when the user enter wrong data .

**Edit :** 
You might use `TryParse` to make sure it's a number :

```
int myInt = 0;
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
bool parsed = int.TryParse(textbox1.Text,out myInt);

if (parsed)
{
    timer1.Interval = myInt;
}
```

Comment: What happen here if the user types a letter instead of a number?

Comment: +1 though note - its better to use NumericUpDown instead, or at least do TryParse to check if number is valid. Also consider to check if number is greater than zero

Comment: Use TryParse with a condition on the out value

Comment: Sorry, but you should show the right way to do this instead of giving a simple warning. I.E. TryParse (or NumericUpDown). By the way, probably the timer has been defined in the designer so, no need to create another one.

Comment: @Steve I added it to the answer

Comment: What happens if the entered value is negative?