# sync data grid view

Tags: c#, .net

i have data grid view that its data source is a data table in form in c#,
how can i make it read table from database continuously
i mean if my program running in many computers in same network and connected with same database , if computer 1 add row to the database its appears automatically in computer 2 without clicking any button to refresh.

```
void load()
    {
        c.connect("sel_dep");
        c.com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter (c.com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        c.open();
        int last = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                dt.Rows.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dd = dt;
            if (dt.Rows.Count != last)
            {
                last = dt.Rows.Count;
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Selected = true; label1.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString(); });
            }
        }
        c.close();

    }
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aa = new Thread(() => { load(); });
        aa.Start();



    }
```

this is my tray

Comment: so what is the error or issue you face ?

Comment: @Islam Gx: One approach would be to make use of a `Timer` and fire up/ call the function to retrieve the data from SQL Database and refresh the `Datagrid.datasource`. This will refresh the grid without having to refresh or press any button.

Comment: application results not appears , cannot use form for another tasks

Comment: @fujiFX how i can make this in code

Comment: Signal R is your best bet to notify all clients of change in data. Other option is periodically pulling the data from database using timer but you have to think of bandwidth and client will only get updated when timer trigger occur.  http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: @Islam Gx r u working on a Winforms (Desktop) app or a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Winforms to create the desktop application, you would not need `timer`.

Simply drag and drop `Timer` control from the Toolbox on your form, in design mode.

```
' The form load should be altered as below
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ' Assume the Timer control is named as 'oTimer'
    oTimer.Enabled = true;
    oTimer.Interval = 60000;    ' In Milliseconds, equates to 1 minute
    oTimer.Start();
}
```

Create the `Tick` event for the `Timer`. This event would be fired each time the interval elapses.

```
private void oTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    <Call your function to initiate/refresh the DataGrid.DataSource within this event>
}
```

In order to further understand how the `Timer` class works, refer [Timer Class (System.Windows.Forms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also refer to Stackoverlow question [Winforms Timer for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174733/winforms-timer-for-dummies) with plenty of resources and tips to master the `Timer` control.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sql Server you can have a look at [Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx), more specifically at [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It can be used to get notifications from sql server, when data changes, into your desktop application

> Built upon the Service Broker infrastructure, query notifications
>   allow applications to be notified when data has changed. This feature
>   is particularly useful for applications that provide a cache of
>   information from a database, such as a Web application, and need to be
>   notified when the source data is changed.