# How do I make an event happen every x seconds? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

How to create make an event call back every x seconds in VB.NET?

Comment: Is it written in WinForms?

Comment: Use a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winforms Timer for Dummies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174733/winforms-timer-for-dummies)

Comment: @Mephy I looked but 1. It's in C# and 2. I couldn't find it.

Comment: The method names are exactly the same in VB and C#. You couldn't find what?

Comment: @Mephy I couldn't find what I needed.

Comment: Just ignore the `;`s and `{}`s and replace `public void` with `Public Sub`. Or you could just refer to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) which has a nice example in VB.

Comment: @theB It doesn't show how do call a function or an event every x seconds

Comment: `timer.Interval = x * 1000` or in the documentation look for the comment `'Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.` for how you'd set it.

Comment: @theB I know how to do that.

Comment: You need to handle the `Timer.Tick` event, which fires every time that the timer expires. (`Handles myTimer.Tick` or [`AddHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx))

Comment: "It's in C# " - you should have no issues with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make it add one to my counter every 10 seconds?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = Counter.ToString
        Me.Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Label1.Text = Counter.ToString
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Oh yeah that does work. :P I didn't realize that "Timer1Tick" (SD) is the whole thing I thought it was one actual tick. Thanks :) @Idle_Mind